# JavaFX Dialog location relative to window (Canvas) position

Tags: java, scala, javafx

I was wondering if there is a (simple) way to place a JavaFX Dialog relative to another GUI-Component.

I have two monitors and the dialog always open in the center of the primary monitor. I know Swing had a method `setLocationRelativeTo(component)` to do exactly what I need but I did not find anything similar.

Btw. I am using Scala and the official jdk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given a `node` that is part of an active scene graph (i.e. displayed on the screen),

```
Bounds bounds = node.localToScreen(node.getBoundsInLocal());
```

will give the bounds of the node in screen coordinates. You can then call `getMinX()`, `getMaxX()`, `getWidth()`, `getMinY()`, `getMaxY()`, and `getHeight()` is needed to position your dialog as required.

Answer (score 3):

To center on a Window is easy, to center on a Node not so much.  The following works for non-waiting dialogs.  The dialog will center on its Owner if set.

```
dialog.initOwner((Window)owner)
```